# Insert bytes in a postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql, file, lzma

I'm trying to insert a file compressed with lzma into a postgresql table with a bytea field.
The problem is that it's unable to format the string and this error occurs:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

To insert the data in the database, i'm using psycopg2:

```
CUR.execute(f"""INSERT INTO table (id, date, bytes) """ + """VALUES ("{file_name}", CURRENT_DATE, %s""", (str(compress(file.read()))[2:-1]))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use f-strings for SQL statements. Use proper variable substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell, without a minimal reproducible sample, but maybe this way:

```
CUR.execute(f"""INSERT INTO table (id, date, bytes) VALUES (%s, CURRENT_DATE, %s""", (file_name, compress(file.read()))[2:-1])
```

Note that all variables are in %s, that what psycopg2 needs. The {file_name} notation is for the format function, that is not used here. You do not need quotes, psycopg2 handles that for you. bytea Postgres type expects a buffer python type, so I removed the str.

Comment: takes care of both issues I mentioned in my answer - upvoted! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter needs to be a tuple. See here:
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#query-parameters

> The second argument must always be a sequence, even if it contains a single variable:

```
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", "bar")    # WRONG
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar"))  # WRONG
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar",)) # correct
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ["bar"])  # correct
```

BTW, why are trying to convert binary data into a string in Python? I'm referring to
"**str**(...)[2:-1]".
I would think you need to pass a bytes object there, e.g.:

```
binarystr = b"bytes here"
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", [binarystr])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both [Alex Funk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10743176/alex-funk) and [Megadest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7487593/megadest).

The issue was both formatting and the variables to format.

I've resolved with:

```
CUR.execute(f"""INSERT INTO table (id, date, bytes) VALUES (%s, CURRENT_DATE, %s)""", [file_name, compress(file.read())])
```